# omitting a point in the plot that is far outside the defined range: I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

pgfplots tries to plot a giant plot despite my upper limit on the y coordinate, where I am trying to zoom in on some data while omitting a point that is way out in space. I think that it should filter out the data that is not within the range that I set. Or is there a reason why this is not done? Here is an MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
 \usepackage{pgfplots}
 \usepackage{filecontents}
 \begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
  a,b
  1,.4
  2,.3
  3,.5
  4,.1
  5,300
  \end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin = 0,ymax = 0.7]
\addplot table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which gives:
    I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.

Also, is there a way to fix this that does not involve manually adjusting my data set before I try to plot?

Thanks

Comment: The pgfplots manual as a very nice section "4.22 Skipping Or Changing Coordinates – Filters". And even though I can subjectively understand that you might be frustrated, do you really think that other users will find your wording more useful than a more neutral language? (Imagine you'd would like to solve a problem and came across such a post.)

Comment: I toned it down some. I will look at it, thank you! Do you think that what I described should be a default filter? So it does not somehow try to plot a point outside of the limits. I am sure it is quite complicated

Comment: or if it hits that then it can try to filter the data with a warning? I am sure that most plotting programs do this...

Comment: I am not sure if there is anything simpler than your answer (could well be but I don't know), yet I'd like to remind you that pgfplots is not a computer algebra system. Given that, I think that it's fair to say that it is an impressive tool.

Comment: I absolutely love pgfplots. Please do not get me wrong, it is just that after I spent two hours messing with this, I felt like it should be a default thing. I was also surprised that nobody else  ran into this issue (at least from my searches), so I thought it is a potential bug

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, a filter can be applied as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{data.csv}
a,b
1,.4
2,.3
3,.5
4,.1
5,300
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ymin = 0,ymax = 0.7]
\addplot +[y filter/.expression={y>0.7 ? NaN : y},] table [x=a, y=b, col sep=comma] {data.csv};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```